# Print Drupal Statistics in node template?

Tags: 7, nodes

When the (core) statistics module is enabled, we get a '50 reads' at the bottom of each node.

Is there any way I can pull that '50' (the node view count) and print it in a node template?

I want to accomplish this without a contribute module.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you using for display? As the data is being printed you should not need a contrib module (assuming you already have Devel on your local, which you should because it's awesome). I would start using dpm on your theme_preprocess_node and page. If this doesn't work please give a little more information on your set up. Such as panels/blocks/views etc.

Comment: @sareed - Not using panels or blocks for this, I simply want to print the node hits statistic that the core statistics module provides in a node--type.tpl.php :) is that clear enough? any ideas?

Comment: @sareed - the core statistics module prints the hits of a node at the bottom of each node like '50 reads'. i just want to know how I can print that counter myself wherever I want in the node template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statistics module provides that data through [`statistics_get()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!statistics!statistics.module/function/statistics_get/7), which returns

> An associative array containing:
>
> - **totalcount**: Integer for the total number of times the node has been viewed.
> - **daycount**: Integer for the total number of times the node has been viewed "today". For the daycount to be reset, cron must be enabled.
> - **timestamp**: Integer for the timestamp of when the node was last viewed.

e.g.

```
$stats = statistics_get($nid);
$total_count = $stats['totalcount'];
$day_count = $stats['daycount'];
```

To get it into a node template, implement `hook_preprocess_node()`, `hook_node_view_alter()`, or `hook_node_view()` (the latter will need to be in a custom module, the other 2 can go in a theme or module).

`hook_preproces_node()` example:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $stats = statistics_get($vars['node']->nid);
  $vars['stats_total_count'] = $stats['totalcount']; 
}
```

And in the template

```
<?php echo $stats_total_count; ?>
```

You'll need to clear Drupal's cache after adding the hook so the theme registry picks it up.

Comment: Done, fortunately it's a pretty simple thing to accomplish. The hook goes in template.php in the theme by the way (not sure how much you know about theming)

Comment: Thank you Clive; but I get these errors after flushing Drupal cache: Notice: Undefined variable: nid in theme_preprocess_node() 
Notice: Undefined variable: stats_total_count in include()

Comment: Didn't update the var for context, the edited version should be ok

Comment: Now I'm getting: Notice: Undefined variable: vars in theme_preprocess_node and Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in theme_preprocess_node... wonder what is wrong ... I appreciate the help

Comment: I got it working! Thank you (so much!!!!!!) Clive! You've taught me a thing or two :)